# How to execute a specific sequence of operations in i3 on start-up?

Tags: startup, i3

Using `exec` in the config file would start an application on startup. Any application to be bound to a workspace when it starts using `assign`. However, how could one do a sequence of operations on start-up?

Specifically, would like to do the following:

1. Open a terminal window in ws2
2. Execute `cd ~/Code && jupyter-lab`
3. `Mod+R`, Right, Right (increase browswer width by two steps)
4. Swap the positions of the browser and terminal
5. F11 (with browser window active)

The exec command can be useful in executing *commands*, such as in step 2, by executing a simple bash script. But how to do the above sequence of operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use jupyter, and I don't know what terminal you are using, so I can't
give a precise answer, but I believe that something like

```
i3-msg workspace 2
i3-msg resize grow width 10 px or 10 ppt
```

would move the focus to workspace 2 (creating it if necessary) and resize the currently active window.
To change directory and launch "jupyter-lab", you could probably use something like

```
urxvt -cd ~/code -e "jupyter-lab"
```

depending on your terminal, or use `xdotool type ...`. Likewise, to issue F11, you can
use `xdotool key F11`, maybe with the `--window` option to specify the correct window.

EDIT: Code that worked for the OP

```
i3-msg workspace 2
gnome-terminal
sleep 1
xdotool type "cd ~/Code && jupyter-lab"
xdotool key KP_Enter
sleep 1
i3-msg resize grow  width 20 px or 20 ppt
i3-msg move left
xdotool key F11
```

Comment: Thank you; your code guided me to achieve what I required. If you don't mind, shall I edit your code to that which worked for me?